# Why were these common operations on collections renamed in Julia?

Tags: julia

Many common operations on collections in Julia such as deleting an item from a Set were renamed recently, with the old functions deprecated.

For example,

```
del(IntSet(1,2,3), 1)
```

now pops up a warning

```
WARNING: del is deprecated, use delete! instead.
```

Some of the renamed functions:

```
@deprecate  push        push!
@deprecate  pop         pop!
@deprecate  grow        grow!
@deprecate  enqueue     unshift!
@deprecate  unshift     unshift!
@deprecate  shift       shift!
@deprecate  insert      insert!
@deprecate  del         delete!
@deprecate  del_all     empty!
```

Why were these renamed? Is appending a ! to functions that change the state of a collection now a convention?

Comment: I have no experience with Julia (hadn't heard of it before now) but I've seen the `!` suffix in other languages.  From a functional programming perspective the `!` indicates a function where the primary purpose is a mutative side effect.  At a glance Julia looks to be deigned with parellel processing in mind and and mutability increases complexity in concurrency: so the `!` would reinforce that that particular call would need additional care in that regard (and an alternate function may be a better alternative).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read the `julia-dev` thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/wKIlMaSj0YE).  Basically, it's simply changing to respect the rule described in the  [arrays](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/manual/arrays.rst) documentation:

> The last function, fill!, is different in that it modifies an existing
>   array instead of constructing a new one. As a convention, functions
>   with this property have names ending with an exclamation point. These
>   functions are sometimes called "mutating" functions, or "in-place"
>   functions.

FWIW I think this is a good idea, at least for `Base`.

Answer (score 7):

The use of `!` was always an explicit convention to indicate mutation, it was just not properly enforced until recently. For `push`, one could easily argue that it's not essential. But using `push!` instead of `push` makes it clear that mutation is happening in this case in precisely the same way that mutation would happen when using `sort!`, which is very different from `sort`.

This exclamation-mark convention exists in Scheme and Ruby and probably several other languages. It doesn't exist in a language like R which wouldn't allow one to perform the mutation without recourse to the underlying guts of the language.